# unable to convert JSON object to associative array in laravel method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following function in my controller:

```
public function index() {
        $tags = DB::table('Tags')->get();
        $tagsArray = array();
        foreach($tags as $tag) {
            $tagsArray[$tag->id] = $tag->tag; 
        }

        $tagsArray = json_decode(json_encode($tagsArray) , true);
        return $tagsArray;
}
```

Now i need to pass $tagsArray as an array to my view but even though i am following the below step:

```
    $tagsArray = json_decode(json_encode($tagsArray) , TRUE);
```

I don't get an associative array , instead the data i get is as follows:

```
{"1":"javascript","2":"browser-bugs"}
```

What am i doing wrong ??

Comment: The output of `json_decode()` is JSON?

Comment: Your controller returns the result of `json_decode` - what did you think is "catching" that `return` statement? The answer posted explains what happens, but you didn't explain what you expected to get back. You're doing nothing wrong since everything works as imagined, but it's not what you expected. What did you expect? That's the problem. If you wanted to pass this to a view, then you need `return view('your_view', ['tags => $tagsArray]);`

Comment: @Mjh sorry about that mate , i'll keep that in mind .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Returning an array directly from the controller will always result in a json object. Laravel automatically converts a php array to json for outputting: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/responses#creating-responses

You have to add this value to a view, preferably by using [the view helper](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-view). Like so:

```
return view('home')->with(['tags' => $tagsArray]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change all your code to this:

```
public function index() {
    $tags = DB::table('Tags')->pluck('tag', 'id')->toArray();
    return view('some.view, compact('tags'));
}
```

This will return an array with `[1 => 'Javascript', 2 => 'browser-bugs']` structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function index() {
    $tags = DB::table('Tags')->get();
    $tagsArray = array();
    foreach($tags as $tag) {
        $tagsArray[$tag->id] = $tag->tag; 
    }
    $tagsArray = json_decode(json_encode($tagsArray) , true);
    return $tagsArray;
}
```